# generic adder "inference architecture": simulation error

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, modelsim, inference

So, I have to create a generic N-bit adder with carry in and carry out.
I have made two fully working architectures so far, one using the generate function and one using the rtl description as follows:

entity:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity adder_n is
generic (N: integer:=8);
port (
    a,b: in std_logic_vector(0 to N-1);
    cin: in std_logic;
    s: out std_logic_vector(0 to N-1);
    cout: out std_logic);
end adder_n;
```

architectures 1 and 2:

```
    --STRUCT
architecture struct of adder_n is
    component f_adder
        port (
            a,b,cin: in std_logic;
            s,cout: out std_logic);
    end component;
signal c: std_logic_vector(0 to N);
begin
    c(0)<=cin;
    cout<=c(N);
    adders: for k in 0 to N-1 generate
        A1: f_adder port map(a(k),b(k),c(k),s(k),c(k+1));
    end generate adders;
end struct;
--END STRUCT

architecture rtl of adder_n is
    signal c: std_logic_vector(1 to N);
begin
    s<=(a xor b) xor (cin&c(1 to N-1));
    c<=((a or b) and (cin&c(1 to N-1))) or (a and b);
    cout<=c(N);
end rtl;
```

Now, my problem is in the third architecture where I'm trying to infer the adder. Even though the following architecture I created compiles just fine, when I try to simulate it, I get a simulation error (on Modelsim), which I have attached at the end of this post. 
I'm guessing there's something wrong with the numeric_std definitions. I am trying to avoid the arith library and I'm still trying to get used to the IEEE standard.
Any ideas are welcomed!! Thank you!

Inference arch:

```
--INFERENCE

architecture inference of adder_n is
    signal tmp: std_logic_vector(0 to N);
    signal atmp, btmp, ctmp, add_all : integer :=0;
    signal cin_usgn: std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
    signal U: unsigned(0 to N);
begin

    atmp <= to_integer(unsigned(a));
    btmp <= to_integer(unsigned(b));
    cin_usgn(0) <= cin;
    ctmp <= to_integer(unsigned(cin_usgn));


    add_all <= (atmp + btmp + ctmp);
    U <= to_unsigned(add_all,N);

    tmp <= std_logic_vector(U);
    s <= tmp(0 to N-1);
    cout <= tmp(N); 
end inference;

-- END
```

Simulation error:

> # Cannot continue because of fatal error.
>   # HDL call sequence:
>   # Stopped at C:/altera/14.1/modelsim_ase/test1_simon/adder_inference.vhd 58 Architecture inference

Comment: It'd help if the read could identify line 58 in `adder_n(inference)`.

Comment: For `    U <= to_unsigned(add_all,N);` I'm showing a bound check error. The left side and right side of the assignment have different lengths. `U`'s length is N+1 while  the expression `to_unsigned(add_all,N)`'s length is N.

Comment: It must be a length issue indeed but after changing the length of the U signal I still get the same error. BTW, line 58 is the line you mentioned.

The full error report is as follows:

> # ** Fatal: (vsim-3420) Array lengths do not match. Left is 9 (0 to 8). Right is 8 (7 downto 0).

Comment: And yet when I changed it I could simulate your design (which would guarantee the bounds (length) match).  Are you sure you actually analyzed and elaborated the right architecture?  You don't change the length of U you change the length of the right hand expression by passing the length to `to_unsigned`. See the answer.

Comment: Yeah I did simulate it on a different machine and it worked for me too. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of U is N+1 (0 to N)

Changing

```
    U <= to_unsigned(add_all,N);
```

To

```
    U <= to_unsigned(add_all,N+1);
```

Will prevent a length mismatch between the left hand side and right hand side of the signal assignment in architecture `inference` of `adder_n`.

The passed parameter to `to_unsigned` specifies the length.